# Use Image from outside plugin for splash screen in eclipse RCP

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp

Currently i am loading my splash screen image for my tool from the plugin.Is it possible to load splash screen image from outside plugin[From other hard drive path]?.My requirement is to give an option to the user to change the splash screen image from my product itself.If Possible please brief me with an example.
Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2):

Try to create custom Splash screen, using following thread for example: [Eclipse RCP application - custom splash screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8345927/eclipse-rcp-application-custom-splash-screen).

Use following extention point to register your SplashHandler:

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.splashHandlers">
   <splashHandler
        class="com.example.application.splash.SlideShowSplashHandler"
        id="splash.slideshow">
   </splashHandler>
   <splashHandlerProductBinding
        productId="com.example.application.product"
        splashId="com.example.application.splash.slideshow">
   </splashHandlerProductBinding>
</extension>
```

In the Splash handler create composite with an image, taken from the location, which was defined by user.