# Eclipse custom splash screen with updating progress monitor

Tags: eclipse, rcp

I'd like to create a splash screen for my eclipse product that has both name/password inputs and a progress monitor with system "Loading..." messages. I've created my splashHandler extension with splashHandler and product mapping. The splashHandler itself is the wizard-produced InteractiveSplashHandler similar to what's described here: [Eclipse RCP application - custom splash screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8345927/eclipse-rcp-application-custom-splash-screen)

I've changed it to use a ProgressMonitorPart so I can get a message area above the monitor bar. I create it in #createUI and It's returned in #getBundleProgressMonitor. But how can I hook it into the application start-up so that it increments the progress and provides the stock messages? I have a plugin_customization.ini with the org.eclipse.ui preference for SHOW_PROGRESS_ON_STARTUP set to true. This file is referenced in my product extension. What am I missing?

Comment: Is your splash showing at all? Eclipse should automatically call the progress monitor during startup.

Comment: yes the splash screen loads and waits for input but the progress monitor does nothing.

Comment: Blocked from answering so posting here: Ok I just figured out that the progress monitor doesn't get called until you close the splash screen. I was hoping for some indication while the user enters their credentials but the way it works seems to be: enter credentials, press OK, progress monitor displays and increments until workbench is ready, splash shell closes, application window appears.

Craig